# How to convert string to json and get the result?

Tags: java, json

My code:

```
List itens = new ArrayList();

itens.add("[{id:0},{descricao:lemb},{mensagem:msg}]");
itens.add("[{id:2},{descricao:lemb},{mensagem:msg}]");
itens.add("[{id:3},{descricao:lemb},{mensagem:msg}]");
for (int i=0; i < itens.size(); i++) {
    Log.v("MyTag", Integer.toString(i) + ":" + itens.get(i).toString());
JSONObject jObject  = null; // json
try {
    jObject = new JSONObject(itens.get(i).toString());
    String projectname = jObject.getString("descricao"); // get the name from data.
    Log.v("MyTag-3", projectname);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.v("MyTag-4", e.toString());
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

Me code returned JSONException:

> org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 36 of
>   [{id:0},{descricao:lemb}, {mensagem:msg}]

Comment: Where did you get the Strings from? This isn't valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON-Objects are not valid. I think you meant something like this:

```
items.add("{'id':0,'descricao':'lemb','mensagem':'msg'}");
```

This works with org.json.json in version 20140107 but the JSON standard is to use double quotes (") instead of single quotes ('), but you have to escape them in Java, this would look like this:

```
items.add("{\"id\":0,\"descricao\":\"lemb\",\"mensagem\":\"msg\"}");
```

Please help yourself at:

- [JSON Introduction](http://www.json.org/)
- [JSON RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159)